# How can I enable or support IPv6 in servers using vCloud?

Tags: iis, ipv6, vmware-vcloud-director

I have web services hosted using vCloud and now I need to know more about the ways to configure IPv6 endpoints for the same.

The only useful info I got is :

*"The quick answer is VCD does not support IPv6.*"

*"If you want to use IPv6 set the gateway to a valid IPv4 gateway (the edge device will only use IPv4) and then once the vApp is online with IPv4, go to each VM and add IPv6 entries as you require."*

Any other info on this will be appreciated.